# How to cast random key with pyautogui?

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

**I am trying to create an AI character to move randomly in game engines for reinforcement learning project. How do I cast (w,a,s,d) keys randomly in a duration ?**

```
def randommove():
    UP   =pyautogui.keyDown('w')
    LEFT =pyautogui.keyDown('a')
    DOWN =pyautogui.keyDown('s')
    RIGHT=pyautogui.keyDown('d')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list and then select from it randomly with random.choice() Also I recommend using the press() function rather than keyDown() as the key will be held down until you use keyUp(). You can set x to be the number of times to repeat the function, or use a while loop to do it indefinitely.

```
def randommove():
    x = 10
    for i in range(x):
        move_keys = ['w', 'a', 's', 'd']
        random_move = random.choice(move_keys)
        pyautogui.press(random_move)
```